# Elasticsearch explore data

Tags: python, elasticsearch, python-3.8, elk

I connected to an elastic search client by using:

```
es = Elasticsearch(
                hosts = myip,
                port = myport,
                http_auth = (myname, mycode),
                connection_class = RequestsHttpConnection,
                scheme = 'https',
                use_ssl = True,
                verify_certs = False,
            )
```

Now i want ta start making queries like these:

```
es.search(index="sw", body={"query": {"prefix" : { "name" : "Mary" }}})
```

But the problem is that i do not know the names of the fields that are in elastic. How can i print the data from elastic or better, print the names of the headers?

Comment: are you looking for index mappings? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-mapping.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to print the available indexes of elastic with the command below:

```
def print_indices(es):
        print(es.indices.get_alias("*"))
```

Then i got all the data by executing the below query:

```
query = {"query": {
            "multi_match": {
                "query" : "*",
                "type" : "cross_fields",
                "fields" : ["*"],
                
                }
            }   
        }
```

However, i got the following message:

> field expansion matches too many fields, limit: 1024, got: 5233')

I don't know how to extend the limit, i guess for smaller databases i works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you check out [Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/index.html), as it provides an easy to use UI into Elasticsearch that lets you explore that data that is stored there

otherwise you might want to look at the [mappings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.14/mapping.html) of the index, that will give you field names (there is no such thing as headers in Elasticsearch language)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mark, indeed in Kibana i can explore the data and find the field names, but i want to implement it in python.